# Django rest framework POST request: JSONDecodeError at /competition-create

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-request

Im trying to simply perform a post request that will save a new competition to the database.

```py
# views.py

class CompetitionCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CompetitionSerializer
    queryset = Competition.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CompetitionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            competition = serializer.save()

            return Response(
                data=CompetitionSerializer(competition).data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                content_type="json")
        return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, content_type="json")

# serializer.py



class CompetitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Competition
        fields = "__all__"
```

response:

[image]

I have tried using regular APIView and switching from `def create(...)` to `def post(...)` but no luck. Also tried to parse the request data content to json.

This is the traceback from the console

```
Internal Server Error: /competition-create
test_deploy_web | Traceback (most recent call last):
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
test_deploy_web |     response = get_response(request)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
test_deploy_web |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
test_deploy_web |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
test_deploy_web |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
test_deploy_web |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
test_deploy_web |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
test_deploy_web |     raise exc
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
test_deploy_web |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
test_deploy_web |   File "/app/view/views.py", line 21, in post
test_deploy_web |     if serializer.is_valid():
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 220, in is_valid
test_deploy_web |     self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 419, in run_validation
test_deploy_web |     value = self.to_internal_value(data)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 476, in to_internal_value
test_deploy_web |     validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 568, in run_validation
test_deploy_web |     value = self.to_internal_value(data)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1899, in to_internal_value
test_deploy_web |     return self.model_field.to_python(data)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/fields/ranges.py", line 80, in to_python
test_deploy_web |     vals = json.loads(value)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
test_deploy_web |     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
test_deploy_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
test_deploy_web |     raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
test_deploy_web | json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `self.request.data` instead of `request.data` and re-check the JSON you are trying to POST?

Comment: @ShrAwanPoudel this did nothing sadly.

Comment: @OliverIlmjärv can you please add your **traceback** instead of the error picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with input JSON that was not being parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing something wired here. So Instead of using this:

```py
# here you are serializing the already serialized data
return Response(
                data=CompetitionSerializer(competition).data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                content_type="json")
```

Try this:

```py
return Response(
                data=serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                content_type="json")
```

Hope this will solve your problem;)

Comment: Still the same problem, nothing changed

Comment: Try changing `serializer.data` with `competition.data`

Comment: the same issue. But i have noticed that the error is raised when is_valid() is called in the if satement.

Comment: Then `print(request.data)` to see what type of data you are getting. Because `JSONDecodeError` error raised if the data to be deserialized isn't a valid JSON.

Comment: Found the answer. It was one of the fields that i was submitting to the api. it had a character that it could not parse to json